# ¿Cómo dibujar el mapa completo en Carbon con React?

Tags: reactjs, carbon, charts

Quiero emplear el [ExperimentalChoropletChart](https://charts.carbondesignsystem.com/react/?path=/story/complex-charts-choropleth-experimental--missing-data) de Carbon en React para dibujar un mapa de Europa, el caso es que para dicho mapa solo tengo datos de varios países, así que el mapa, aunque le paso todos los polígonos necesarios, solo dibuja aquellos países de los que tiene datos.

En este [entorno de aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sluwnc?file=src%2Foptions.js,src%2Fdata.js,src%2Findex.js) está simplificado el problema: tengo polígonos de España, Francia e Italia, pero como podéis ver solo dibuja los países de los que tiene datos y parcialmente Francia.

Me preguntaba si habría alguna manera de obligar al componente a que dibuje todos los polígonos y que solamente coloree aquellos de los que tiene datos.